# mailto doesn't work with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, mailto

So this what I use :

```
btnContactUs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{

navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:test@test.com"), "_blank");
}
```

I also tried with `"_self"` and it doesn't do anything ( I know the button work ).

You need to know that It's not an application embbeded in an html page.
It's a local .swf that I run ( Ctrl + enter (with the .fla) and  it doesn't work ).

Comment: hmm, that should work fine. Have you tested it on a server? My guess is the global security settings for flash is making it not work

Comment: no not on a server, so how do I change this security settings ?

Comment: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html ...add your drive or folder to to that list and see if that helps

Comment: have you tried the link outside the flash IDE? like open the swf or throw it in a browseR? I tried it in my flash IDE and it opened gmail in chrome which is my default mail

Comment: open the swf doesnt work but if i throw it on firefox it work

Comment: yeah it work on firefox but I don't have outlook that why it doesnt work. But how can I make it say ("doesn't work please install outlook" if he doesnt have )

Comment: Have you set your browser's default e-mail program? If you have none set then likely it will not do anything. For FireFox, http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Changing%20the%20e-mail%20program%20used%20by%20Firefox

Comment: whoa, don't ever make anyone install outlook

Answer (score 0):

```
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:test@test.com"), "_blank");
```

works whether you have it set to access network or local files only, I'm not sure why you can't get it to work, have you tried a simple trace for the `fl_ClickToGoToWebPage` function to make sure it is called at all?

Answer (score 0):

We can use following code with ExternalInterface 
where 'url' is mailto: link URL. i.e. mailto:abc@xyz.com?subject=Hello&body=defg

```
//Mailto Links from Flash
    ExternalInterface.call("function(link){var wEmail = window.open(link, '_blank'); setTimeout(function(){ wEmail.close();}, 70);}", url);
```